# Retrieve the first day of the last month for a given date

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp

Given a string like `2016-05-25` I want to get the first day of the previous month (e.x `2016-04-01`).

I have tried this

```
$month_ini = new DateTime("first day of last month"); 
$month_end = new DateTime("last day of last month");
```

but I get the first day of the previous month relative with the current month, which is not what I want.

Specifically I will get random dates from clients (with format 'Y-m-d') and I have to display the first day of the previous months relative with the client's requested month.

Comment: soooo.. WHAT exactly have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: "I want to get the first day of the previous month" - that's nice, so why don't you, then?

Comment: I dont want to get the first day of the previous month....I want given a random date string like the one I have at my question retrieve the last day of the previous month

Comment: the answered that marked as duplicate did not help me

Comment: what you want to do with day AND month, the linked answer does with just the day. it shouldn't be too hard to apply the same method to the month.

Comment: The linked answer display what I want compared with the current month. I want to retrieve the first day of the last month compared a random date string...it not the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do this for any month, instead of the current month

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-05-25');
$date->modify('-1 month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-t'); // 2016-04-30
echo $date->format('Y-m-01'); // 2016-04-01
```

Comment: This solution is wrong in some case. you would try if the ```$date``` is 2016/12/31

Comment: @KennethChan Yeah. `modify` is screwy on months. Which is why [the manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) `Beware when adding or subtracting months`

Answer (score 1):

> Pre-Request: System should be in UTC

```
$firstDayLastMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of last month'));
$lastDayLastMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of last month'));
echo $firstDayLastMonth .'<br>'. $lastDayLastMonth ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for any month:

```
$datestart = date('Y-m-01',mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, 1, date("Y")));
$dateend   = date('Y-m-t' ,mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1, 1, date("Y")));
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution I used is like that:

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-12-31');
$date->modify('FIRST DAY OF -1 MONTH');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); //2016-11-01
```